# problema en PHPMYADMIN sobre la confi de almacenamiento, donde no me permite acceder a otras BD

Tags: phpmyadmin

No permite realizar cambios en ninguna BBDD, además que tampoco permite acceder a ellas, ya que aparece el cuadro de la imagen

[image: Se muestra la interfaz de phpmyadmin y el erro que existe]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega detalles relevantes acerca del problema que tienes, ademas estas incluyendo contenido no valido.